# Dr Racket snake movement

Tags: racket, game-development

how can I make an object move to different directions in dr racket's bigbang function, on tick? As an example, for the snake game when left arrow is pressed the snake should keep going to left but I don't know how to combine the handle-key and on-tick function

I know there are 4 possibilities but I don't know how to use something like "" if handle-key is left, keep going left. if handle-key is down, keep going down

```
(define (next-game s)
   ;(make-snake (+ SPEED (snake-x s)) (snake-y s) (snake-l s)))
   ;(make-snake (snake-x s) (+ SPEED (snake-y s)) (snake-l s)))
   ;(make-snake (- (snake-x s) SPEED) (snake-y s) (snake-l s)))
   ;(make-snake (snake-x s) (- (snake-y s) SPEED) (snake-l s)))
```

Comment: What kind of object should I use to represent your snake (list, struct, hash...) (and does it matter to you)? Also, if you already wrote some other functions (or you have exact instructions from the teacher), you can add them to your question.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Store the snake's direction. Change the direction in the key handler, update the position in the tick handler.